# TextMesh vs MeshRenderer, Which is more efficient?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I'm working on a simple game that display many texts on screen. There is only about 30 different strings or so, and they don't change during gameplay. So should I:

1. Render all of those string to textures and draw it with a Quad mesh (MeshRenderer)
2. or just stick with classic TextMesh?

I do know that pre-render all of those string may take up storage memory, TextMesh don't ruin the text on big screen and they will render it on the run anyway.

So which one is more efficient?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it implied? If you are looking for memory efficiency, use TextMesh. If you're looking for (possibly) faster rendering performance, use MeshRenderer.

But if you currently have neither memory nor performance issues, take the path of least resistance (aka the most *effective* implementation). You can always optimize for efficiency later on, after you've determined the exact cause (or major causes) of performance degradation or memory consumption.